# Calling from China to Home country (India) without internet access

Tags: india, china, communication

I am from India, will go to China. I want to make call from China to INDIA. I am not sure about internet access to use Android Apps like Skype or Google talk. What is the best possible way to make call? I have heard about calling cards. Does it require Internet access or local number to call?

Comment: Skype works in China.

Answer (score 1):

No. You should be ok with a phone card. You do not need internet access to use a calling card. But it does require you to have a telephone with an associated phone number. You can even use a pay phone (if you can find one). If you have a mobile phone, you can buy a sim card with an international calling plan.

What that said, Skype will be ok to use in China. Google talk might be blocked. Alternatively, you can use WeChat or Whatsapp to make calls over the internet.